# Extracted excel file from another excel using aspose cells is not opening

Tags: java, excel, ole, aspose-cells

I am trying to extract ole objects from excel files using aspose cell.
While excel file is successfully extracted at desired location, the extracted file is not opening in excel.
I am getting this msg while I open :
[Message I am getting when I open the extracted excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7XtE.png)

I have tried aspose-cells-20.3 and 20.8 as well but same issue.

Code for extracting the excel file is :

```
    private static void extractEmbeddedImages(Workbook workbook) throws Exception {
        // Get the OleObject Collection in the first worksheet.
        OleObjectCollection oles = workbook.getWorksheets().get(0).getOleObjects();
        PrintWriter ws=new PrintWriter(new File(sDataDir + "/" + sFileNameWithoutExt + "_EmbeddedFiles.txt"));
        //PrintWriter ws=new PrintWriter(new File(sDataDir + "/EmbeddedFiles.txt"));


        // Loop through all the ole objects and extract each object. in the worksheet.
        for (int i = 0; i < oles.getCount(); i++) {
            if(oles.get(i).getUpperLeftColumn() < excludeColFrom) {
                if (oles.get(i).getMsoDrawingType() == MsoDrawingType.OLE_OBJECT) {
                    OleObject ole = (OleObject) oles.get(i);

                    String sRow=""+ole.getActualLowerRightRow();

                    com.aspose.cells.Cell cell  =  workbook.getWorksheets().get(0).getCells().getCell(Integer.parseInt(sRow), ole.getLowerRightColumn());
                    String sOrgFile=ole.getSourceFullName();

                    if(sOrgFile == null) //This code is only skipping those file with null resourceFullNme. 
                    {

                        if(ole.getProgID().equalsIgnoreCase("Bitmap Image"))
                            sOrgFile = ole.getLowerRightColumn()+ ".jpg";

                    }
                    else if(ole.getProgID().equalsIgnoreCase("Acrobat Document"))
                        sOrgFile = sOrgFile+".pdf";

                    String sFnamme= new File(sOrgFile).getName();

                    sFnamme = sFnamme.substring(sFnamme.lastIndexOf("\\")+1);

                    boolean isExits=isAlreadyExits((Integer.valueOf(sRow)-1)+"_"+sFnamme);
                    if(isExits)
                        sFnamme=(Integer.valueOf(sRow)-4)+"_Temp_"+sFnamme;
                    else
                        sFnamme=(Integer.valueOf(sRow)-4)+"_"+sFnamme;

                    FileOutputStream fos;
                    try {
                        byte[] data = ole.getObjectData();
                        if(data != null) {
                            fos = new FileOutputStream(sDownloadDir + "/" +sFnamme);

                            try {
                                fos.write(data);
                            } catch (IOException e1) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            try {
                                fos.close();
                                ws.println(sFnamme);

                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ws.close();
    }
```

Please help .

Thanks in advance

-Swapnil

Comment: Check [this](https://superuser.com/questions/657597/how-to-troubleshoot-automatic-update-of-links-has-been-disabled) out, maybe it can help

Comment: Where in code you are extracting Excel file or your code is not complete? Please provide your complete code and provide your source template Excel file (you may share the file via some file sharing services).

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: I got the solution.Problem was that, aspose cells handles every ole object except excel file in a same way.


```
if(ole.getFileFormatType() == FileFormatType.XLSX) {
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        Workbook oleBook = new Workbook(is);
        oleBook.getSettings().setHidden(false);
        oleBook.save(sDownloadDir + "/" +sFnamme);
       }
       else {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(sDownloadDir + "/" +sFnamme);
        fos.write(data);
        fos.close();
       }
```

Comment: good to see your issue is sorted out :)